# toISOstring not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timezone

Im giving date as a string and then trying to convert it to ISO.

Here is what I have been doing:

```
var dateValue = "Tue Sep 29 2015 16:50:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"
alert(dateValue.toISOString());
```

But this is returning me the following error 
**"toISOString is not a function"**

Why is this?

Comment: That's because `toISOString()` is exposed by `Date` objects, not strings.

Comment: docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this?

Becase your `dateValue` is a *string*, and `toISOString` isn't a method on strings (it is on dates).

To use it, you'll need a `Date` object. There's **no guarantee** in the specification that the format you've shown will be successfully parsed by anything built into JavaScript, so you'll need to parse it with something that *does* make that guarantee: Either your own code, or a library like MomentJS.

The format in question is quite easy to parse if it's stable:

```js
var months = {
  jan: 0,
  feb: 1,
  mar: 2,
  apr: 3,
  may: 4,
  jun: 5,
  jul: 6,
  aug: 7,
  sep: 8,
  oct: 9,
  nov: 10,
  dec: 11
};
var dateValue = "Tue Sep 29 2015 16:50:00 GMT+0530 (IST)";
var rex = /^.{4}(.{3}) (\d{2}) (\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) GMT([+-]\d{4})/;
var data = dateValue.match(rex);
snippet.log("Day: " + data[2]);
snippet.log("Month: " + months[data[1].toLowerCase()]);
snippet.log("Year: " + data[3]);
snippet.log("Hour: " + data[4]);
snippet.log("Minute: " + data[5]);
snippet.log("Second: " + data[6]);
snippet.log("Offset: " + data[7]);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

...then just use the `new Date(year, month, ...)` constructor to create the date, and adjust the time based on the offset (be sure to use the UTC methods on `Date`).